# How to convert an SQL query which contains a lateral derived table to JPQL?

Tags: java, sql, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jpql

I am trying to convert the following SQL query into JPQL in order to fit it into a Spring Data @Query. I cannot find any documentation mentioning this specific case. Has anyone ever tried, and succeeded? I would like to avoid resorting to a native query.

```
`SELECT
  salesperson.name,
  max_sale.amount,
  max_sale_customer.customer_name
FROM
  salesperson,
  -- calculate maximum size, cache it in transient derived table max_sale
  LATERAL
  (SELECT MAX(amount) AS amount
    FROM all_sales
    WHERE all_sales.salesperson_id = salesperson.id)
  AS max_sale,
  -- find customer, reusing cached maximum size
  LATERAL
  (SELECT customer_name
    FROM all_sales
    WHERE all_sales.salesperson_id = salesperson.id
    AND all_sales.amount =
        -- the cached maximum size
        max_sale.amount)
  AS max_sale_customer;``
```

This query can be found on [MySql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lateral-derived-tables.html). The query I am trying to use is different but it follows the same principle, and I am unable to find any documentation on how to convert it to JPQL.

Answer (score 0):

**Please Follow this steps**

> - First identify what will be your select fields
> - Write an interface considering your select fields for example  InterfaceGarDto

```
 public interface InterfaceGarDto {
     Long getIdGar();
     LocalDate  getStartDateLink();
     String getToplink();
     String getIdPrdeTauxRef();
     LocalDate getEndDatePrde();
}
```

> - Considering your entity/domain write your JPQL query
> - Use EntityManager to get your expected result from below code

```
Query q = entityManager.createQuery("[ your jpql query ]");
List<InterfaceGarDto> resultList  = q.getResultList();
```

Comment: @Ems good day, If you find difficult to write JPQL query, I can help you if you share related entity / domains with me

Comment: Hi Sahab, thank you so much ! I am conscious it would be quite long and tedious for the both of us to try and recreate the whole context of my specific query. I have updated my question to put a more generic query.

Comment: seems like you updated your previous query, here is sample jpql 

SELECT s.name, max_sale.amount, max_sale_customer.customer_name
FROM Salesperson s
JOIN (
    SELECT a.salesperson.id, MAX(a.amount) AS amount
    FROM AllSales a
    GROUP BY a.salesperson.id
) AS max_sale ON s.id = max_sale.id
JOIN (
    SELECT a.salesperson.id, a.customer_name
    FROM AllSales a
    WHERE a.amount = (
        SELECT MAX(a.amount)
        FROM AllSales a
        WHERE a.salesperson.id = s.id
    )
) AS max_sale_customer ON s.id = max_sale_customer.id

Comment: Salesperson, AllSales are your entity , you have write an interface considering your select fields s.name, max_sale.amount, max_sale_customer.customer_name and complete the steps describe in the answer